# SQL Server Script to create a new user

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I want to write a script to create a `admin` user ( with `abcd` password ) in SQL Server Express.
Also I want to assign this user `admin` full rights.

Answer (score 248, accepted):

Based on your question, I think that you may be a bit confused about the difference between a *User* and a *Login*.  A *Login* is an account on the SQL Server as a whole - someone who is able to log in to the server and who has a password.  A *User* is a *Login* with access to a specific database.

Creating a *Login* is easy and must (obviously) be done before creating a *User* account for the login in a specific database:

```
CREATE LOGIN NewAdminName WITH PASSWORD = 'ABCD'
GO
```

Here is how you create a *User* with db_owner privileges using the *Login* you just declared:

```
Use YourDatabase;
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = N'NewAdminName')
BEGIN
    CREATE USER [NewAdminName] FOR LOGIN [NewAdminName]
    EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'NewAdminName'
END;
GO
```

Now, *Logins* are a bit more fluid than I make it seem above.  For example, a Login account is automatically created (in most SQL Server installations) for the Windows Administrator account when the database is installed.  In most situations, I just use that when I am administering a database (it has all privileges).

However, if you are going to be accessing the SQL Server from an application, then you will want to set the server up for "Mixed Mode" (both Windows and SQL logins) and create a Login as shown above.  You'll then "GRANT" priviliges to that SQL Login based on what is needed for your app.  See [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337562.aspx) for more information.

UPDATE: Aaron points out the use of the sp_addsrvrolemember to assign a prepared role to your login account.  This is a good idea - faster and easier than manually granting privileges.  If you google it you'll see plenty of links.  However, you must still understand the distinction between a login and a user.

Comment: Exactly what I required, thank you. I didn't expect it to be so easy - and for it to work perfectly!!

Answer (score 45):

Full admin rights for the whole server, or a specific database?  I think the others answered for a database, but for the server:

```
USE [master];
GO
CREATE LOGIN MyNewAdminUser 
    WITH PASSWORD    = N'abcd',
    CHECK_POLICY     = OFF,
    CHECK_EXPIRATION = OFF;
GO
EXEC sp_addsrvrolemember 
    @loginame = N'MyNewAdminUser', 
    @rolename = N'sysadmin';
```

In newer versions (see [the note in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addsrvrolemember-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)) you should use:

```
ALTER SERVER ROLE sysadmin ADD MEMBER MyNewAdminUser;
```

You may need to leave off the CHECK_ parameters depending on what version of SQL Server Express you are using (it is almost *always* useful to include this information in your question).

Comment: Exactly what i want
I was trying to create login with  c#  using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Login class. but i couldn't create. this works with simple code in c# 
thanks

Answer (score 8):

You can use:

```
CREATE LOGIN <login name> WITH PASSWORD = '<password>' ; GO
```

To create the login (See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189751.aspx) for more details).

Then you may need to use:

```
CREATE USER user_name
```

To create the user associated with the login for the specific database you want to grant them access too.

(See [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173463.aspx) for details)

You can also use:

```
GRANT permission  [ ,...n ] ON SCHEMA :: schema_name
```

To set up the permissions for the schema's that you assigned the users to.

(See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187940.aspx) for details)

Two other commands you might find useful are [ALTER USER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176060.aspx) and [ALTER LOGIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189828.aspx).

Answer (score 6):

If you want to create a generic script you can do it with an Execute statement with a Replace with your username and database name

```
Declare @userName as varchar(50); 
Declare @defaultDataBaseName as varchar(50);
Declare @LoginCreationScript as varchar(max);
Declare @UserCreationScript as varchar(max);
Declare @TempUserCreationScript as varchar(max);
set @defaultDataBaseName = 'data1';
set @userName = 'domain\userName';
set @LoginCreationScript ='CREATE LOGIN [{userName}]
FROM WINDOWS 
WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE ={dataBaseName}'

set @UserCreationScript ='
USE {dataBaseName}
CREATE User [{userName}] for LOGIN [{userName}];
EXEC sp_addrolemember ''db_datareader'', ''{userName}'';
EXEC sp_addrolemember ''db_datawriter'', ''{userName}'';
Grant Execute on Schema :: dbo TO [{userName}];'
/*Login creation*/
set @LoginCreationScript=Replace(Replace(@LoginCreationScript, '{userName}', @userName), '{dataBaseName}', @defaultDataBaseName)
set @UserCreationScript =Replace(@UserCreationScript, '{userName}', @userName)
Execute(@LoginCreationScript)

/*User creation and role assignment*/
set @TempUserCreationScript =Replace(@UserCreationScript, '{dataBaseName}', @defaultDataBaseName)
Execute(@TempUserCreationScript)
set @TempUserCreationScript =Replace(@UserCreationScript, '{dataBaseName}', 'db2')
Execute(@TempUserCreationScript)
set @TempUserCreationScript =Replace(@UserCreationScript, '{dataBaseName}', 'db3')
Execute(@TempUserCreationScript)
```

Comment: I have unintentionally downvoted this answer but now I cannot undo my downvote without editing. I have put junk text just to remove my downvote but now I cannot remove neither junk text neither the downvote... I am sorry

Answer (score 3):

```
CREATE LOGIN AdminLOGIN WITH PASSWORD = 'pass'
GO


Use MyDatabase;
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = N'AdminLOGIN')
BEGIN
    CREATE USER [AdminLOGIN] FOR LOGIN [AdminLOGIN]
    EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'AdminLOGIN'
    EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'adminlogin', @rolename = N'sysadmin'
END;
GO
```

**this full help you for network using:**

```
1- Right-click on SQL Server instance at root of Object Explorer, click on Properties
Select Security from the left pane.

2- Select the SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode radio button, and click OK.

3- Right-click on the SQL Server instance, select Restart (alternatively, open up Services and restart the SQL Server service).

4- Close sql server application and reopen it

5- open 'SQL Server Configuration Manager' and tcp enabled for network

6-Double-click the TCP/IP protocol, go to the IP Addresses tab and scroll down to the IPAll section.

7-Specify the 1433 in the TCP Port field (or another port if 1433 is used by another MSSQL Server) and press the OK 

8-Open in Sql Server: Security And Login  And Right Click on Login Name And Select Peroperties And Select Server Roles And 
  Checked The Sysadmin And Bulkadmin then Ok.
9-firewall: Open cmd as administrator and type: 
      netsh firewall set portopening protocol = TCP port = 1433 name = SQLPort mode = ENABLE scope = SUBNET profile = CURRENT
```

Answer (score 0):

This past week I installed Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Developer Edition on my dev box, and immediately ran into a problem I had never seen before.

I’ve installed various versions of SQL Server countless times, and it is usually a painless procedure. Install the server, run the Management Console, it’s that simple. However, after completing this installation, when I tried to log in to the server using SSMS, I got an error like the one below:

SQL Server login error 18456
“Login failed for user… (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)”
I’m used to seeing this error if I typed the wrong password when logging in – but that’s only if I’m using mixed mode (Windows and SQL Authentication). In this case, the server was set up with Windows Authentication only, and the user account was my own. I’m still not sure why it didn’t add my user to the SYSADMIN role during setup; perhaps I missed a step and forgot to add it. At any rate, not all hope was lost.

The way to fix this, if you cannot log on with any other account to SQL Server, is to add your network login through a command line interface. For this to work, you need to be an Administrator on Windows for the PC that you’re logged onto.

Stop the MSSQL service.
Open a Command Prompt using Run As Administrator.
Change to the folder that holds the SQL Server EXE file; the default for SQL Server 2014 is “C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn”.
Run the following command: “sqlservr.exe –m”. This will start SQL Server in single-user mode.
While leaving this Command Prompt open, open another one, repeating steps 2 and 3.
In the second Command Prompt window, run “SQLCMD –S Server_Name\Instance_Name”
In this window, run the following lines, pressing Enter after each one:
1

> CREATE LOGIN [domainName\loginName] FROM WINDOWS
>   2
>   GO
>   3
>   SP_ADDSRVROLEMEMBER 'LOGIN_NAME','SYSADMIN'
>   4
>   GO
>   Use CTRL+C to end both processes in the Command Prompt windows; you will be prompted to press Y to end the SQL Server process.

Restart the MSSQL service.
That’s it! You should now be able to log in using your network login.