# Problems configuring a user for a SQL Server Express 2012 ODBC DSN

Tags: sql-server, odbc, sql-server-2012-express

Good morning everyone!!!

I'm having a problem configuring an ODBC DSN for SQL Server Express 2012 to be used in a Scada program. For this I made a DB and I created a new user and password with the queries used in the first reply of [the following thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601186/sql-server-script-to-create-a-new-user). My problem comes when I'm configuring my ODBC DSN, at the end when I do the test of the connection comes the next error:

```
Attempting connection
[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'Admin'.

TESTS FAILED!
```

I have tried different things but they don't work. If someone had the same problem as I do now and know an answer I will appreciate a lot if his/her answer can help me.

EDIT: I forgot to say that I'm trying this in Windows 7.

Many thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, it was simple: reinstall SQL Server Express... Why??? The Authentication Code was failing due that I choosed the Windows Certification and not a Mixed or SQL Certification. Now everything is solved. Sorry for my simple and silly question.