# How to add users to a SQL Server database in a C# Winform

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms, ssms

I am trying to insert users into a SQL Server database, but not the way you are thinking.

Usually, in SQL Server Management Studio, one would enter new users through the Security - Logins wizard. But how can one do this in a C# Winform application?

Basically, my Winform would have various fields to capture, but the important ones are the username field and all the selected roles

[image]

In this form, once a users clicks Add, the data will be stored into a separate SQL Server table. I would like to add the user to the database credentials

[image]
[image]

Once they have been added to the security credentials, they have the default data:

- Windows user/s
- Default schema of [dbo]
- If possible, a server role of public
- The user mapping is the main area to focus on here. For each role that the user must have, that must be assigned to them for that database. So if a user's roles are Capturer and Admin, then they will have those role memberships mapped to that database for the newly created user. The roles that are selected do exist in the db, so there shouldn't be any errors here.

[image]

Is this possible to do via C# Winforms? Would this be possible using a dataset? Would this be conventional C# code ie.

> SqlConnection //the rest of the code follows here

or would there have to be a new interface/form to utilise?

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601186/sql-server-script-to-create-a-new-user

Comment: @x... thanks. I will definitely try something like this. I can create a sql query to add the user and the assign the roles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use SSMS, and right click on any object (including logins, users, etc), you can choose options to see the generation script:

[image]

[image]

This will show you what commands you need to execute to create that object. Remember that you need both the login (to the server) and user (to the database) entries. So: just issue equivalent commands! For some things like passwords, you many need to consult the `CREATE LOGIN` etc documentation, since the server is unable to script those out. Note that this does mean your application needs to run with enough access to manage users.

Comment: Thanks very much. combined with the comment on my question and this, I'm making a query to add the users and their roles. I can also invoke the system stored procedures